# Cant remove childnode without making childNode (message) not showing at all

Tags: javascript

I've have tried alot of different ways with removing the child and nothing has worked so faar, well it has to some degree, either i have no messages or i keep getting message that just add to the span without deleting the other

Tried reading up on how to remove the child, and have tried every different ways i've found to remove it, my code might be wrong on creating the child and append it etc. since it's the first time i use this way. Been trying with a while loop to remove, and the one that is already outcommented in the code, and with firstChild. and with different names instead of msg.

My code looks like this in my script:

```
function validateName(input, id)
{
    var res = true;
    var msg = document.getElementById(id);
    var error = document.createElement("span");
    var errorMsg = "";

    if (input == "" || input < 2) {
        res = false;
    //        removeChildren(msg);
            errorMsg = document.createTextNode("Input is to short!");
            error.appendChild(errorMsg);
            id.appendChild(error);
    }
    if (input >= 2 && input.match(/\d/)) {
        res = false;
    //        removeChildren(msg);
            errorMsg = document.createTextNode("Name contains a number!");
            error.appendChild(errorMsg);
            id.appendChild(error);
    }
    if (input >= 2 && !input.match(/\d/)) {
        res = true;
    //      removeChildren(msg);
    }
    return res;
}
```

My small test page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <script src="Validator.js"></script>
        <script>
            function v1(e,id) {           
                if(validateName(document.form1.namefield.value, id) == false) {
                    document.getElementById("be").src="NotOkSmall.jpg";
                }
                if(validateName(document.form1.namefield.value) == true) {
                   document.getElementById("be").src="OkSmall.jpg";    
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Validation testing, HO!</h1>
        <form name="form1" action="submit">   
            <div id="div1">
                <input type="text" name ="namefield" id="f1" onkeydown="v1(be, div1)" >
                <image id="be" src="NotOkSmall.jpg" alt="OkSmall.jpg" />
            </div>
            <input type="button" value="GO" onClick="v1(be)">
        </form>
    </body> 
</html>
```

If anyone have any ideas to make it work I for one, would be a very happy guy :), as i have said before i am not even sure the creation of child is the correct way in this case. but as it works when i have removed removeChildren, it does write the correct messages, just dont delete any of them. So something must work..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You had some errors in your code like `id.appendChild(error);` where you had to use `msg.appendChild(error);`. Anyway I don't see a need to append/remove child nodes in this case. Just use hidden error placeholder and show it when you want to display an error message.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
        <script src="Validator.js"></script>
        <script>
            function v1(imgId) {
                var img = document.getElementById(imgId),
                    val = document.form1.namefield.value;
                img.src = img.alt = validateName(val) 
                    ? "OkSmall.jpg" 
                    : "NotOkSmall.jpg";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Validation testing, HO!</h1>
        <form name="form1" action="submit">   
            <div id="div1">
                <input type="text" name ="namefield" id="f1" onkeyup="v1('be');" >
                <image id="be" src="NotOkSmall.jpg" alt="NotOkSmall.jpg" />
                <span id="error-message" class="invis"></span>
            </div>
            <input type="button" value="GO" onClick="v1('be');">
        </form>
    </body> 
</html>​​​​​​​​​
```

**CSS:**

```
​.invis {
    display: none;
}​
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function validateName(input) {
    var res = true,
        errorMsg,
        errorContainer = document.getElementById('error-message');

    if(input.length < 2) {
        res = false;
        errorMsg = "Input is to short!";
    }

    if(input.length >= 2 && /\d/.test(input)) {
        res = false;
        errorMsg = "Name contains a number!";
    }

    if(res) {
        errorContainer.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        errorContainer.innerHTML = errorMsg;
        errorContainer.style.display = 'inline';
    }

    return res;
}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/TuUzW/)**

Comment: Thanks it is very appreciated, and seems alot easier then childNodes, i just have one problem, first i tried correcting my code to your example, then it did not work, then i just copyied everything into new files and tried again, but to no avail, even though your example and my copy is identical.

Comment: i created a file named invis.css with your the CSS code inside, also tried writing a <style>.invis { display: none;} </style> in the html but also not working, i believe it is the CSS that what is wrong since, the code is identical to yours and the only thing i have been a bit unsure of is the CSS part. Since your DEMO works beautiful!!

Comment: Maybe some existing styles are overriding the rules from your `invis.css`. You can set more specific CSS selector like `#div1 > span.invis` or just replace `class="invis"` with `style="display: none;"`

Comment: I had a mistake in my example. It should be `/\d/.test(input)` instead of `input.test(/\d/)`. Just fixed it.

Comment: aaah swwet it works :) thanks alot for all the help Evgeniy!! much appreciated